# PowerShell scanning registry objects and comparing

Tags: powershell, registry

I'm looking to scan a registry key for it subkeys whilst comparing their values value. For example:

```
HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\mail\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676
```

This registry key contains two subkeys. I want to go through the two subkeys until I find the one that has its Account Name set as the current logged in user. Once I detect to right key I also want to add values to the keys properties.

```cs
if ((Test-Path $path1) -eq $true) {
    $registry = Get-ChildItem "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\"

    foreach ($key in $registry) {
        $key | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "00000002"}
        Write-Host "i found 00000002"
    }    
}
```

[image: This image shows two subkeys]

[image: Shows values in keys]

I want to scan each subkey in this case 00000001 and 00000002 and see which one of these has the account name variable set to the current user. Essentially how to a go through and pull values from each $key object.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is here. What problem are you facing? What do you expect your code to do, and what does it actually do? Are you getting errors? What do they say?

Comment: What is your question? I don't see a reason you shouldn't **do** what you **want**

Comment: I have updated original post. If you guys can help that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out on my own. Essentially you want to use get-childitem on the current get-childitem output. So for my example I ended up using the following code snippet.

```
    $path1 = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\*"  ## Reg key location for calling signature file 
$path2 = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\mail\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676\*"     ## Reg key location for calling signature file alternate


if ((test-path $path2) -eq $True) {

     Get-ChildItem $path2 |
     Get-ItemProperty |
     Where-Object{
          $_.'Account Name' -match $env:USERNAME
     }| Set-ItemProperty -name 'New Signature' -value $env:USERNAME
       }
```